# How does Python distinguish explicitly passed None as argument in built-ins

Tags: python, built-in, python-internals

I experimented with the next code:

```
>>> f = object()

# It's obvious behavior:
>>> f.foo
Traceback (most recent call last):       
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'foo'

# However, the next one is surprising me!
>>> getattr(f, 'foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'foo'

# And this one returns None as expected:
>>> getattr(f, 'foo', None)
```

Then I found this pseudo-signature of `getattr()` in the PyCharm IDE:

```
def getattr(object, name, default=None): # known special case of getattr
    """
    getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value

    Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
    When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
    exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.
    """
    pass
```

My question is how does python distinguish this two scenarios of using `getattr()` (and maybe other functions) internally? And is it possible to do something similar entirely in the client side code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @scytale said, the pseudo-signature of `getattr` doesn't quite correspond to its implementations. I've seen attempts to replicate the behaviour in pure Python that look something like this:

```
class MyObject(object):
    __marker = object()

    def getvalue(key, default=__marker):
        ...
        if key is __marker:
             # no value supplied for default
             ....
```

In other words, use a marker value that a caller cannot easily supply to check if no value was given as the default rather than `None`.

Comment: Except that `getattr` can accept **any** argument as the default, including your `MyObject.__marker` and distinguish it from the case where the third parameter is missing. Consequently your answer fails to show how `getattr` distinguishes the two cases (yes it could use a hidden object that can't be retrieved from python side, but it doesn't) and also it fails to show how you could do it in "client code".

Comment: @skyking: I never said it was a perfect replication of the behaviour. It is, however, sufficient for most use-cases. I.e., I took the "how can I achieve a similar result" to be more important than "how does this work under the hood."

Comment: I'd rather use __marker = object() as this is using the object instance not object type.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek: whoops! That's what I intended!

Answer (score 4):

`getattr` is implemented in C so how it's done differ a bit from how it's done in python. In C there are a couple of calling conventions, `getattr` is using what's called `METH_VARARG` which means that it expects unspecified number positional arguments passed as a tuple, the function then checks that it's either a tuple of length 2 or 3 (via `PyArg_UnpackTuple`) and acts accordingly (when unpacked the default argument will when omitted be a `NULL` pointer which is different from any python object).

It's similar of what could be done in python:

```
def mygetattr(*args):
    if len(args) != 2 and len(args) != 3:
          raise Exception
    try:
        return getattr(args[0], args[1])
    except AttributeError:
        if len(args) == 3:
            return args[2]
        raise
```

But normally in python one would actually explicitely state the parameters that's mandatory and then use `*args` to handle the optional parameters (ie `def mygetattr(obj, key, *args):...`)

Answer (score 2):

`getattr` is a built-in - therefore it is implemented in C - the pseudo-signature is not a precise guide to how it works.

Comment: I know, but this is not an answer to my question. I asked about how is it implemented under the hood and how can I emulate such behavior in a client code.

Answer (score 2):

The question is technically answered well enough.

But in IDEs you will probably get an "ugly" function signature hint like this:
[image: Ugly signature]
`_MISSING` or whatever you choose as identifier can be quite confusing here.

To improve programmer's UX (and maybe automatically generated code documentation too), the use of `overload` decorator ([Python documentation: typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)) is a good choice to see this result:
[image: Better signatures]
You get both signatures displayed as you are probably familiar with from builtins and other Python packages.

Example:

```py
from typing import overload

_MISSING = object()


@overload
def myfunc(value):
    pass


@overload
def myfunc(value, default):
    pass


def myfunc(value, default=_MISSING):
    if default is _MISSING:
        print("Missing default on call", value)
    else:
        print(value, default)


myfunc(1, 2)  # Output: 1 2

myfunc(1)  # Output: Missing default on call 1
```

This overload mechanics only affects the IDE (and generated documentation).

During runtime the last non decorated function (which is always required) will technically simply overwrite the previous decorated functions in the namespace for `myfunc`.

Typing and type hints are also recommended but not included in the code snippet because it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would go in the same direction as @skyking but also allow using named arguments like this:

```
def getattr(object, name, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(args) == 1:
        # third positional argument is used as default
        default = args[1]
    elif 'default' in kwargs and len(kwargs) == 1:
        # provided as named argument
        default = kwargs['default']
    elif len(kwargs) > 0 or len(args) > 0:
        # unknown arguments
    else:
        # no 'default' was supplied
```

In the above code, you can insert the processing code and exceptions to be raised wherever it is appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

[`getattr` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) says

**getattr(object, name[, default])**

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

If you want to implement same try this

```
def mygetattr(obj, attr, default):
    ret_val = defaule
    try:
        ret_val = getattr(obj, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return ret_val
```

Comment: The question was about how to handle the case where `default` argument is omitted differently. Your example doesn't do that.