# Python inheritance with generic object - how to call method only if it exists in that object

Tags: python

So I have this piece of code:

```
class QuerySetUpdateOverriden(QuerySet, object):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, method):
            self.method()
            return
```

I want to override the update method and if the second class that it inherits has a specific method, call that too.

But I get an error on the line containing the if statement saying "name method is not defined".

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What/where is `method` defined? If you're trying to get the name `update` programmatically, [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066627/how-to-get-a-method-name-in-python).

Comment: The parameter for `hasattr` should be a string, because you don't pass variables to functions, you pass **values**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass a string with the name, so:

```
if hasattr(self, 'method'):
    self.method()
    return
```

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood the question, but then isn't that just a typo? Or a duplicate of this: [How to check whether a method exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580532/how-to-check-whether-a-method-exists-in-python)

Comment: this was it. Sorry :(